# Ruby - Asynchronous Mailing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, redis, actionmailer

I'm quite new to Ruby on Rails and want to send an e-mail asynchronously to make my app respond faster. The synchronous sending works fine and would be my alternative.

I've found some sites and defined the gems 'resque_mailer', 'redis' and 'resque' in my Gemfile and installed them via the `bundle install` command. My mailer looks like:

```
class Contact < ActionMailer::Base 
include Resque::Mailer  

default from: "<private>"

  def contact(email, bandName, respondMail, message)
    @message = message
    @respondMail = respondMail
    @bandName = bandName

    mail(:to => email,
         :subject => "subject")
  end
end
```

The Controller-Call to send the mail looks like:

```
Contact.contact(band.email, band.name, params[:respondMail].to_s, params[:message].to_s).deliver
```

If I try to send my mail now asynchronously I'm getting the following error which is caused by the "contact" call:

```
Timed out connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379
```

Unfortunately I've got no idea how to solve this. Can someone please tell me which steps I must make to send a mail asynchronously? If possible there should be no extra database columns.

Comment: Did you install and launch [redis](http://redis.io)?

Comment: Obviously not. I thought all will be done automatically after installing the gem and launching the rails-server. How can I install and start redis?

Comment: There's link in my comment. It's pretty simple, actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for resque and resque_mailer to work you need to install redis. You can find more about redis here: http://redis.io/download

If you are new to rails, all the external tools and dependencies can be quite overwhelming. If you don't have an application with extreme load you should consider using a simpler job queue like https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job. It does not depend on further external services and uses your current database to store the jobs. The only thing you need to do is to keep the workers up.

Comment: Thank you for the tip with 'delayed_job'. With the gems 'delayed job' and 'daemons' it works really fine and is absolutely sufficient for my purposes. :)

Comment: Now I've got one more question due to the use of "delayed_job". When I run "rake jobs:work" parallel to my "rails server" it works fine. But how do start the job worker with my "rails server" command? In the above mentioned installation manual there is some code in the section "Running Jobs" but I don't know how to manage this. Where should I put this code? Maybe you can help me again ...

Comment: The whole Idea behind a background processing queue, is that it runs in a separate process. Running `rails server` will just boot the process to handle incoming requests. You need to tweak your environment to also start `rake jobs:work`.